# need device Driver Program for PCI interrupt

Tags: driver

I am using a PCI based card with **PCI-9054** PCI controller and one **Xilinx** **FPGA**.Actually i need to generate an interrupt through **PCI INTA#** line.Can anyone help me in the driver program for getting the interrupt in `"cat /proc/interrupts"`. I am feeding an external signal to the FPGA which i am routing to the "pci_lint_n" signal.This signal will be going as an input to **PCI9054** from which it will generate an **INTA** interrupt line.
can somebody help me in doing the same.
Thx in advance.